# Assembly $0 vs x0?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, riscv

In different tutorials I have seen some write `$0` and others write `x0` which of them is correct, and if both what's the difference?

Plus, what would happen if I write into the first register x0?

Comment: As far as I know, RISC-V registers are typically either written by their register name (`x0`) or their ABI name (`zero`). Is that stuff targeting a different assembler, and are you sure that it's a register field, not a literal being given the hexadecimal value `0`?

Writes to `x0` are ignored.

Comment: ignored and not erros?

Comment: That's correct. It's hardwired to 0. An instruction that writes its result to `x0` like `ADDI x0, x0, 0` is typically used as a no-op, and is completely valid to do.

Comment: MIPS's zero register is called `$0` or `$zero`.  MIPS and RISC-V somewhat related, both 32-register pure RISC machines without FLAGS, but they are separate ISAs.  Possibly you were looking at tutorials for MIPS?  gcc and clang both just use `zero` to name the zero register, `x0`.  https://godbolt.org/z/Wv7e5G

Comment: RARS, for example, doesn't support `$0`, only `x0` and `zero`.